# Insert image into the title HTML attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html

I use poshy jQuery bubble and I need to insert an image inside the bubble.

With this plugin, the text inside the bubble was generated with the title attribute (I have different text, its not the same image for each link, it's why I need that).

```
<a class="demo-tip-yellow" title="<img src='/static/images/school/parents/btn_nav  /btn_change.png'> " href="<?=site_url('school/parents/children/'.$item['id'])?>">
```

Is it possible to insert a string inside the title attribute, if yes, how?

Comment: Not possible, `title` only accepts text.

Answer (score 3):

**Please don't misuse the `title` attribute**, it is a very important one also in terms of accessibility (and even SEO). It should only contain simple text.

You could use the `data-` attributes to store the image source and retrieve it through jQuery. This is the best way you could achieve this.

Using this HTML:

```
<a data-tooltipimage="/static/images/school/parents/btn_nav/btn_change.png" 
    title="Something descriptive" 
    href="#" 
    class="demo-tip-yellow">
```

you can easily retrieve the attribute through

```
$('demo-tip-yellow').attr('data-tooltipimage');
```

or from jQuery 1.4.3, you can simply use

```
$('demo-tip-yellow').data('tooltipimage');
```

because jQuery automatically fetches `data-` attributes into the data object.

I don't know this exact plugin, but if you check the documentation, you certainly have a way to control where does the plugin get its data from and how it is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I checked Poshy Tip documentation: http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

There is a way to set the content by a function, so the following may very well work:

```
<a href="http://linkurl" id="link" data-tooltipimage="http://imageurl" title="sometitle">link...</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link').each(function() {
    var img_url = $(this).data("tooltipimage");
    var tooltip = img_url ? "<img src='"+img_url+"' alt='' />" : $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).attr("title","");
    $(this).poshytip({
        content: function(updateCallback) {
            return tooltip;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You should set the `data-tooltipimage` only when you want image tooltip.

**EDIT:** an other approach, with a hidden element, where you can put anything:

```
<a href="http://linkurl" id="link" title="sometitle">
    link...
    <span class="hidden-tooltip-data" style="display: none;"><img />...</span>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link').each(function() {
    var tooltip = $(".hidden-tooltip-data",this).html();
    $(this).attr("title","");
    $(this).poshytip({
        content: function(updateCallback) {
            return tooltip;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT 2:** and another:

```
<a id="link1" href="http://linkurl" title="sometitle">link...</a>
<span id="link1_tooltip" style="display: none;"><img /><a></a>...</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link').each(function() {
    var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
    var tooltip = $("#"+linkid+"_tooltip").html();
    $(this).attr("title","");
    $(this).poshytip({
        content: function(updateCallback) {
            return tooltip;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would +1 for actually checking how the plugin works, but you should not really use `title` for this.

Comment: Well same goes to you for beeing strict, not misusing the title attribute (even if it gets emptied after all, since this is a tooltip plugin) but forcing some non well-fomed jquery attributes. (ps.: Kapa már megint üvöltözöl!)

Comment: yes but some tip dosent't   have image , I dont want image  everywhere

Comment: @inti Even if it is emptied with Javascript, the HTML (which should be semantic) will store a URL as the title of that link (imagine a screenreader reading it out). Which of my jQuery attributes are malformed?

Comment: @bazmegakapa the attribute is fine, just not a standard attribute name, but never mind, it's a fine solution :)

Comment: @inti  Thx ,  but some link can have  two picture  and some juste  one... I think i will chance my plugin for a better  jquery bubble and more customizable

Comment: @user763045 You may face the same problems elsewhere, if you find this plugin satisfying, try to think of a way to add more of the data you want to display. I sometimes use the approach to place a hidden element after, or inside my links, and get the tooltip data from there. I may add this to the answer...

Comment: @inti    Thx that work :) , i need to learn a lots  about jquery :)  thx :P

Comment: humm ... only one probleme , i can't insert a link inside  the  <span class="hidden-tooltip-data">  

:S

Comment: I wonder if there is a chance you can click on a link inside a tooltip, which only appears if you hover over another link... But well, there is always a way...

Comment: @inti Sorry for asking again, but which attribute is not standard? `data-` attributes are absolutely standard from HTML5.

Comment: @bazmegakapa well, then it was my bad... sorry. It was my failed attempt to poke back for "misusing title", and I failed miserably :) Btw, your point with screen reading is absolutely valid, wonder if such program sees an <img> in the title, would it read the alt attribute instead?

Comment: @inti I don't think so, no program would expect HTML in `title`. The `data-` attributes were introduced exactly for this purpose, to stop misusing other attributes (I've seen everything from `title` through `alt` to even `href` for storing arbitrary data). And I did not mean to poke you, nothing personal.

Comment: @bazmegakapa btw thanks for the `data-` attribute tip, I never heard of it before. Will use it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this HTML:

```
<a class="tipped" href="/path/to/something.html">
    <img src="something-tooltip.png" alt="Real text of the tooltip."/>
    Something
</a>
```

Combined with this CSS:

```
a.tipped img {
    display: none;
}

a.tipped:hover img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

You won't need JS, but of course you can use it to animate the tooltip. In this case you can drop the `a.tipped:hover img` rule.

This way you won't commit an assault against the web,

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin are you using ?

Try to html encode `<img src='/static/images/school/parents/btn_nav/btn_change.png'>`. In PHP it's `htmlentities()` I think.

Answer (score 0):

while you should not be storing markup in the title tag, you could use:

```
<a class="demo-tip-yellow" title="<?php echo htmlentities(<img src='/static/images/school/parents/btn_nav  /btn_change.png'>);?> " href="<?=site_url('school/parents/children/'.$item['id'])?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the > inside an attribute might break the HTML as well. If you just want to have an image inside an overlay/bubble/lightbox i suggest looking at http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Fancy only do a bubble on click ?  Bubble need to appear on a hover. 

I need to put two image ( with a link on each image ) insite  a bubble on a hover ( for my link )

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I didn't realize you were doing a tooltip type functionality. I've used jquery tools tooltip before, and changed it to a click. The default is hover: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html